# If for $\epsilon \gt 0 \space x \in (a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$, Prove that $x \in [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $a,b,x$ are real numbers such that $a<b$. We have :
$\forall \epsilon \gt 0 \space \space x\in (a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$

Prove that $x\in[a,b]$.

Note: I tried to assign values to $\epsilon$ and i noticed that the smaller $\epsilon$ is, i get closer to the desired result.  But it seems that i need to assign something related to limits  to $\epsilon$ . I don't know if i can do that. ( Something like $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}$ )

Comment: Your attempt leads to a direct proof, actually. You would be done if you proved that $$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(a-1/n,b+1/n\right)=[a,b]$$ which can be done fairly routinely.

Comment: @NicholasStull Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler than that, you don't need to use limits or anything. Suppose to the contrary that $x$ is *not* in $[a,b]$. Then either $x < a$ or $x > b$.

If $x < a$, let $\epsilon = a-x > 0$. Then by hypothesis $x$ must belong to
$$(a - \epsilon, b+\epsilon) = (x, b+\epsilon),$$
i.e. we must have $x > x$, a contradiction.

Similarly if $x > b$, let $\epsilon = x-b>0$, then $x \in (a-\epsilon,x)$, contradiction again.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x\not\in [a,b]$. Then either $x<a$ or $x>b$ and WLOG assume $x<a$. Then let $\epsilon_0=a-x$. Then with $\epsilon={1\over 2} \epsilon_0$ we see that $x\not\in (a-\epsilon, b+\epsilon)$, a contradiction.